# Android APK not working properly after build using Expo React Native

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I've been working on an app, and I have been using both the Android emulator and my Android device for testing using Expo.

It works great, everything goes perfect. However, I just built an Android APK (I executed `expo build:android`), and I can see the login of my app, but after introducing credentials, it kinda shows like it closes the app and then restores it, but now it keeps showing just a blank screen.

Here is a gif showing you exactly what happens.

https://giphy.com/gifs/hdtXNeM2s5Dx7FnbNJ

Also, here's the code of my App.js, which works showing the `<AuthNavigator />` (The login screen), but it stops working when a user is set and then `<AppNavigator />` does not appear.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";

import AppNavigator from "./app/navigation/AppNavigator";
import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";
import AuthContext from "./app/auth/context";
import authStorage from "./app/auth/storage";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const restoreUser = async () => {
    const user = await authStorage.getUser();
    if (user) setUser(user);
  };

  if (!isReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={restoreUser} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Also my app.json, just in case it's needed:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Agro-Mobile",
    "slug": "Agro-Mobile",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./app/assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.smartbase.agrocognitive",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./app/assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: see this guide for debugging help: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/debugging/

Comment: Any updates regarding this? @Samuel Mariña

Comment: @WaelDimassi well, since the app was not a complex thing, I changed from bare workflow to managed workflow, and that made it work. However, I don't know the solution for the problem I was talking about

Answer (score 2):

In app.json you need change:

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.smartbase.agrocognitive",
  "versionCode": 1
```

for this

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.agrocognitive.agrocognitive",
  "versionCode": 1
```

in other words you need only change the name of company for the name of your app, make sure use only lowercase characters without simbol. The folder that your create have the same name of your app. And for other people delete any commentary in App.js.

This works for me in bluestacks emulator and in my phone running apk file
I hope help you

Answer (score 0):

try  npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

i solved this problem with this

Answer (score 0):

Installing the packages `react-native-screens` and `react-native-safe-area-context` solved the issue for me.

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```