# Android APK from Expo React Native not even opening

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Today I finished writing my first React Native app, so I am new to it. I used Expo and wanted to use it on my phone without Expo Go.

So I used [this tutorial](https://dev.to/chinmaymhatre/how-to-generate-apk-using-react-native-expo-kae), but that don't work for me (apk crashing).

Also tried [with adb](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/), but that still doesn't work.

Tried also answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64035716/android-apk-not-working-properly-after-build-using-expo-react-native), but still nothing works.

I am getting the message "App still stopped working" and [this is how it looks like when I try to open the app](https://giphy.com/gifs/2dRHwpSCyj8UC0pPjY)

Current App.tsx

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { StatusBar, setStatusBarStyle } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/contexts/AuthContext';
import { Provider as PreacherProvider } from './src/contexts/PreachersContext';
import { Provider as TerritoryProvider } from './src/contexts/TerritoriesContext';
import { Provider as MinistryGroupProvider } from './src/contexts/MinistryGroupContext';
import { navigationRef } from './src/RootNavigation';
import SwitchNavigator from './src/navigators/SwitchNavigator';


setStatusBarStyle('light')

const App = () => {

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'FontAwesome': require('./assets/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf'),
    'InterThin': require('./assets/fonts/inter/Inter-Thin.ttf'),
    'InterRegular': require('./assets/fonts/inter/Inter-Regular.ttf'),
    'InterSemiBold': require('./assets/fonts/inter/Inter-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'MontserratRegular': require('./assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    'MontserratSemiBold': require('./assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'PoppinsThin': require('./assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Thin.ttf'),
    'PoppinsSemiBold': require('./assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'PoppinsRegular': require('./assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf')
  });

  if(!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <PreacherProvider>
        <TerritoryProvider>
          <MinistryGroupProvider>
            <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
              <SwitchNavigator />
            </NavigationContainer>
          </MinistryGroupProvider>
        </TerritoryProvider>
      </PreacherProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
    
  )
  
}


export default App;
```

Current app.json

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Territory Manager",
    "slug": "territorymanager_mobile",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/tm_icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/tm_logo_zielony.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#28a745"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/tm_icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#28a745"
      },
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "package": "com.territorymanager_mobile.territorymanager_mobile",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: see this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUS_BjOHi-c or Click this link to proceed : https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/2057 or https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6229